# PHP Mpdf - move table to next page if it doesn't fit in actually page

Tags: php, mpdf

I have to create dynamically a PDF file using Mpdf. The page/s contain multiple tables.

I would like to move the table to the next page if it doesn't fit in the page. At the moment it brokes in 2 pieces (once piece in one page, check the image I added).

Is there any possibility to move the table to the next page? Like I said, I create the file dynamically, so I don't know how many tables I have or how long will be the last row (with text) of the table.

[![At the end, it breaks in 2 pieces][1]][1]

Here is a table example:

```css
 body {
      font-family: Arial;
      line-height:12px;
      color: #000000;
      font-size:10px;
    }
    p{
      margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
    h1 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-bottom:15px;
    }
    .nabidka-container {
      width:1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .nabidka-container .products:first-child {
      margin-bottom:40px;
    }

    .nabidka-container .products{
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin: 35px 0 40px 0;
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      overflow:wrap;
      display:block;
      page-break-inside:auto
    }
    .nabidka-container .products,.nabidka-container .products tr td, .nabidka-container .products tr th {
      page-break-inside: initial !important;
    }
    .nabidka-container .products td {
      width:25%;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      padding:2px;
      text-align: center;

    }
    .nabidka-container .products td.foto {
      border: 0px;
    }
    .nabidka-container .products td.bezramu {
      border: 0px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .nabidka-container .products .tab_popis {
      width: 200px;
    }
    .nabidka-container .products .tab_hodnoty {
      width: 50px;
    }
    .nabidka-container .products .bold {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .nabidka-container .products .italic {
      font-style: italic;
    }
    .nabidka-container .products .left {
      text-align: left;
    }
    .nabidka-container .products .right {
      text-align: right;
    }
    .nabidka-container .products .price {
      background-color: #cecece;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nabidka-container">
<table class="products" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab_popis foto">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty foto"><img src="https://devlocal.optimtop.cz/storage/files/sources/images/products/p283_01_small.jpg" class="foto"></td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty foto"><img src="https://devlocal.optimtop.cz/storage/files/sources/images/products/p213_01_small.jpg" class="foto"></td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty foto"><img src="https://devlocal.optimtop.cz/storage/files/sources/images/products/p275_01_small.jpg" class="foto"></td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty foto"><img src="https://devlocal.optimtop.cz/storage/files/sources/images/products/p188_01_small.jpg" class="foto"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab_popis foto">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty bold">Válcové brikety</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty bold">Brikety RUF</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty bold">Brikety RUF</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty bold">Noční brikety</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab_popis left">Kód</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">DBVMPR800</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">RUFHEX840</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">RUFMEX840</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">NOCVB720</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab_popis left">Hmotnost balení</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">10 kg</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">10 kg</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">10 kg</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">10 kg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab_popis left">Hmotnost palety</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">800 kg</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">840 kg</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">840 kg</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">720 kg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab_popis left">Počet balení na pal.</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">80</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">84</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">84</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">72</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab_popis left">Průměrná výhřevnost</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">18.8 MJ/kg</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">18.5 MJ/kg</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">18 MJ/kg</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty">18 MJ/kg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab_popis left price">Cena/ks</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">41.88 Kč</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">46.43 Kč</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">40.48 Kč</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">53.47 Kč</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab_popis left price">Cena/paleta</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">3350 Kč</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">3900 Kč</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">3400 Kč</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">3850 Kč</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab_popis left price">Cena/tuna</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">4188 Kč</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">4643 Kč </td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">4048 Kč</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty price">5347 Kč</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab_popis bezramu"></td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty italic ">SUPER CENA  průměr 9 mm</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty italic ">100% buk</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty italic ">SUPER CENA  dub,buk,jasan</td>
    <td class="tab_hodnoty italic ">dlouhá doba žhnutí</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try the **css**  `page-break-after: always;` adding in each table you want to separe. Read [this](https://code.cubewise.com/canvas-docs/page-break-in-pdf-report) for more information.

Comment: `page-break-after: always;` will break any tables :) I don't ned to have for examples 8 tables in 8 pages :)

Comment: It works, maybe is another **css** problem, share the code and maybe we can help you.

Comment: @Roy I added an exmaple table: Already tried `page-break-after: always;` on tables, but it breaks all tables. In my example is on table. Imagine there are 8 tables. In my case, let's say 2 tables will entire fit in the page, but the third won't fit. So I have tro move the table to the next page with the rest of tables.

Comment: And `page-break-inside: avoid`? Check if removing `page-break-inside: initial !important;` works....

Comment: @Roy `page-break-inside: initial !important;` not helped. Adding `page-break-inside: avoid` It will shrink my table to fit. That's not what I need. I want to break the page and move the table to next page.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer yourself, not as an edit to the question. Then mark it as accepted so this whole question shows as solved.

Comment: @Finwe Done.Sorry for that. I wasn't sure I should answer myself or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to fix it using `page-break-inside: avoid`. But you need to add `$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;` to your mpdf object or attribute `autosize="1"` to your table element. (without **shirt_tables_to_fit** or **autosize**, it will add one table to one page (at least that was the behaviour in my case).

For more info about table shrink check [Tables - Tables - mPDF Manual](https://mpdf.github.io/tables/tables.html)